# Narrow Bing News API search by "publish time"

Tags: bing, bing-api

Is it possible to narrow my searches by PUBLISH TIME using the bing api?

For example, getting the same results on bing api vs http://www.bing.com/news/search?q=SOPA&p1=%5bNewsVertical+Interval%3d%227%22%5d&FORM=PTFTNR ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you can do with the News SourceType is described [in the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250884.aspx).

There is currently no option to filter by publish time, the only workaround I see is to use the SortBy option and filter out the older results on your side, but this can unfortunately show up some less relevant news.

Also note the paragraph explaining that LocationOverride, Category, and SortBy are mutually exclusive. It might pose a problem if you need to use a combination of those.

You can give your feedback and submit a feature request on the [Bing API Developer Forum](http://www.bing.com/community/developer/default.aspx).

HTH.